# I'm not able to get RSS feed working. I get 'XML parsing failed'

Tags: rss

After I updated my site, I'm not able to get the RSS working.
I used to get this RSS icon in the address bar in my web browser (opera), but now it's not there any more.

I try accessing the following URL: http://www.norwegianfashion.no/feed/

But I only get this error message:

```
XML parsing failed
XML parsing failed: syntax error (Line: 3, Character: 0)

  1: 
  2: 
  3: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  4: <rss version="2.0"
  5:    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  6:    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
```

Testing it in a [feed validator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.norwegianfashion.no%2ffeed), is says I have a blank line at the start of the file.
Clicling he [help link](http://feedvalidator.org/docs/error/WPBlankLine.html), says that Wordpress has a tendency to create empty spaces :(

Does this mean I have to go through each template file, include file and plugins and remove the `?>` at the end?

Anything else that could cause my problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate issues here.

Feeds are not detected by browser, because information for that is not being output in page body. I believe the current way of adding those links is declaring it in theme with `add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');` in `functions.php`, see [Feed Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Feed_Links) in Codex.

Other issue is that something spits out unwanted new lines at the very start of output, both for your feeds and regular pages as well. Usually this is caused by such whitespace outside of `<?php ?>` tags somewhere in theme or plugin file, it can be rather hard to track down. `functions.php` of theme is always good place to check for this first.

Comment: You were spot on - in both issues. My Function.php did indeed have empty space after `?>` and that was what caused this issue.